# Checkbox highlight not working when its checked

Tags: html, checkbox, highlight

i have included some checkboxes within my html page so the user can check and uncheck them, i also wrote the style to highlight the checkbox borders and also the label but still nothing work.

can do with a bit of help.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="createartwork" id="createartwork"> 
<label class="label-for-check" for="createartwork">I want your Designer to create my artwork</label> 


input[type=checkbox]:checked  + label::after{
    background-color: #FD6418;
}


input:checked {
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
}
```

Comment: This might be a typo, not sure though. `label:after` instead of `label::after`

Comment: the `:after` pseudo-selector requires a `content: 'x'` to appear.

Comment: @Roy_Dorsthorst it's not :) https://www.impressivewebs.com/before-after-css3/

Comment: @Roberrrt thanks for providing that documentation! makes sense.

Comment: @Roberrrt  thanks for your comment theres no difference between them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 <input type="checkbox" name="createartwork" id="createartwork"> 
 <label class="label-for-check" for="createartwork">I want you  to create my artwork</label> 

:checked + label {
  background-color: #FD6418;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

Try this.

Comment: What is 'checked' in this context?

Answer (score 0):

You're a bit off track, you cannot style the original `<input>` tag, you *can* fake a new checkbox with your label, so using the code you provided:

HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="createartwork" id="createartwork"> 
 <label class="label-for-check" for="createartwork">
 I want you  to create my artwork</label>
```

CSS:

```
input[type=checkbox]
+ label::before {
    content: '';
    width: 5px;
    height: 5px;
    background-color: #FF0;
    margin-right: 5px;
    padding: 0px 5px;
}
input[type=checkbox]:checked + label::before{
    content: 'x';
    background-color: #FF0;
    margin-right: 5px;
    padding: 0px 5px;
}

input[type=checkbox] {
    display: none;
}
```

And of course, [a working example](http://codepen.io/robertspier/pen/pEBmqY)

Comment: the link to your working example is not the right link and i have  tried that still not working